# Rich nontrivial examples of topological spaces to keep in mind for learning topology

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, intuition

What are some nontrivial topological spaces with rich structures (and which possibly occur in higher mathematics) to keep in mind as an example to test various topological theorems and/or to build intuition behind them?

I only have the usual metric space topology on $\mathbb{R}^i$ where $1 \leq i \leq 3$ in my mind (besides the toy examples which are given in the book for that particular theorem and which are mostly too shallow in structure to be used for building intuition for other theorems) while checking various topological theorems or guessing correctness of some topological facts ; but that don't exactly provide me with the correct intuition for the generality/limitedness of the theorem.

What are some of the topological spaces which I should internalize and study properly to have a good intuition re: point set topology (as in, normal point set topology; not into too much arcane rarely explored avenues of it)

Comment: Counterexamples in topology by Steen and Seebach, Jr. provides a number of topological spaces for which one or another property fails.

Comment: @GoranMalic I am aware of the (nice) book, but it contains far too many counterexamples to check every time (what I'm looking for is a nice and small set of topological spaces to add to my stack of examples so that everytime I read a theorem I can check it against them)

Comment: What about sphere, torus, and "torus with more that one holes"? Another good family of example is the projective spaces.

Comment: These are the "good examples" - but maybe you want some "bad examples", since although they rarely appear in "higher maths" (as far as I know), they might provide you some intuition for why various additional hypothesis are needed for the main theorems in point-set topology. So here are some "bad examples" : the first uncountable ordinal with the order topology, the Sorgenfrey plane, and the Cantor set (as a subspace of the real line: it is a metric space, but has some ridiculous properties).

Comment: I find your question too broad (and I wonder what would qualify as normal and what not), at any rate you may find examples online at $\pi$-base https://topology.jdabbs.com/